# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finalproject

Tags: jsp

this is my test.jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
import="java.sql.*"
import="java.io.*"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Final Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>New Registration Page</h1></center>
    <table border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr>
                        <form action=Profile.jsp method="get">
                        <td>First Name*:</td> <!-- we need a button that says show profile then link it here -->
                        <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><center><input type="submit" value="Submit!"></center></td>
                        </form>
                    </tr> 
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

This file is connected with the profile.jsp. 
When i submit the test.jsp,No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finalproject error comes up from

```
<% 
Class.forName("java.sql.Connection");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finalproject", "root", "vietforlife");
String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Username, Password1, Password2, Email FROM userid WHERE FirstName = '"+firstname+"'"); 
%>
```

I think my database is not connected with the jsp file. 
I followed the instructions from similar question, but that was not work. 
can you guys help me?

Comment: `:3306` is dispensable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **wrong driver class name**
Change

```
Class.forName("java.sql.Connection");
```

To

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Have a look at the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

### Update

> it gives java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error.

You need mysql-connector jar in class path in order to avoid `ClassNotFoundException`.
You can download it from [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

#### Related Links

- [Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC DriverManager Interface](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)
- [Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Comment: if i use that one, it gives java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error. That's why i changed it to java.sql.connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

and don't forget to include the jar file for this.